# how do i manually parse output of .dump() file into a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

how do i manually parse output of .dump() from a text widget that has italic and bold text in it to a different text widget to load it along with its text format.

this is the code if it helps, the text should be saved along with text format but when the file is open the text format is gone:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()

textpad=Text(root, font='Consolas 11')
textpad.pack()

def save():
    content=textpad.get(1.0,'end')
    filename=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='open file',filetypes=(("text","*.txt"),("html",".html"),("all types","*.*")))
    openit=open(filename,'w')
    openit.write(content)
    openit.close()

def opens():
    textpad.delete(1.0,'end')
    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(title='open file',filetypes=(("text","*.txt"),("html",".html"),("all types","*.*")))
    openit=open(filename,'r')
    content=openit.read()
    textpad.insert('end',content.strip())
    openit.close()

def boldtext():
    textpad.selection_get()
    textpad.tag_add('bold','sel.first','sel.last')
    textpad.tag_config('bold',font='Consolas 11 bold')

savebtn=Button(text='save',command=save)
savebtn.pack()
openbtn=Button(text='open',command=opens)
openbtn.pack()
bold=Button(text='bold',command=boldtext)
bold.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.get()` will not include those formatting information.  Also what is `.dump()`?

Comment: based on what i experience so far, when i used dump method to a text widget it extracts the information about that text widget including the tags information

Comment: @acw1668: `dump` is a method that gets the formatting information along with the text.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't include any call to `dump` or any attempt to parse it's output. It's not clear what the problem is that you need help with since the formation of the output of `dump` is documented.

Comment: I suggest you start with some research on how to use the `dump` command. Here's an answer with an example that converts the data to html: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52915925/7432. Instead of emitting html tags, you can call the text widget `insert` method to reproduce the information in another text widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` widget `dump` method returns a list of tuples. Each tuple will be of the form (*key*, *value*, *index*). *key* will be one of the following: `text`, `mark`, `tagon`, `tagoff`, `image`, or `window`. *value* will be dependent on the key. *index* is the location in the text. For example, with `tagon` and `tagoff` the value will be the name of the tag. For `text` it's a string of text characters.

Consider a text widget with the tags "bold" for bold and "italic" for italic.  It might look something like this:

[image: screenshot of text widget with bold and italicized text]

When you call the `dump` method you will get something like the following (line breaks added for clarity):

```
[('text', 'Here is a sentence with ', '1.0'),
 ('tagon', 'bold', '1.24'),
 ('text', 'bolded', '1.24'),
 ('tagoff', 'bold', '1.30'),
 ('text', ' and ', '1.30'),
 ('tagon', 'italic', '1.35'),
 ('text', 'italicized', '1.35'),
 ('tagoff', 'italic', '1.45'),
 ('text', ' text.', '1.45')]
```

A conversion function needs to loop over that data and process each key. For example, for every `tagon` you can add the tag to a list, and for every `tagoff` you can remove it from the list. For the `text` tag you just insert the text with the current list of tags.

The solution might look something like this:

```
def undump(dump_data, target):
    tags = []
    for (key, value, index) in dump_data:
        if key == "tagon":
            tags.append(value)
        elif key == "tagoff":
            tags.remove(value)
        elif key == "mark":
            target.mark_set(value, index)
        elif key == "text":
            target.insert(index, value, tags)
```

Given a original text widget named `source` and a second text widget named `target`, you would call it like this:

```
undump(source.dump("1.0", "end-1c"), target)
```

Comment: Why did you use `target.mark_set(value, index)` instead of `target.mark_set(value, "paste_index")`?

Comment: @TheLizzard: that example is broken. I've updated it.

Comment: The marks get moved after every insert because the default gravity is `"right"`. To fix that, you can add `target.mark_gravity(value, "left")` after the `mark_set`. Btw `.dump` doesn't report the mark gravities so there is no way to exactly clone a text widget using `.dump`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: you can clone the widget if you pass the widget rather than the results of calling `dump`, but you're right that if you only have the information from `dump` then you can't fully clone the widget since you also don't get the configuration of the tags, tabstops, and other attributes of the widgets. This specific question wasn't about cloning a widget, but in how to take the information from the `dump` method to add the text to a widget. This answer addresses that questions.