# With tkinter is there a way to embed formatting to imported text?

Tags: tkinter, text, formatting, embed

I have an application that uses a button to open a Toplevel dialog. I'd like to be able to embed text formatting in this static file. Formatting would be size, font, bullets, etc. The less desirable way to do this is to create a class dedicated to the help text. I'd rather not do this because the code will be compiled making the text in the class inconvenient to access when necessary. An external text file makes far more sense if possible.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Looked at HTML markup.

UPDATE: Can I create text in the Text widget and save the text to an external file with the formatting tags?

Comment: Do you need any other program be able to read the data (ie: is a tkinter-specific solution OK)?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: [how do i manually parse output of .dump() file into a text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74192814/7432)