# Restore a tk.Text widget from dump results

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there an existing method that accepts the return data from a `.dump` call on a tk.Text widget, and restores the widget to the state that the data represents? I really just need a yes or no, and if yes, the name of the method. It's obvious to me how to do it manually, so please do not put any effort into that kind of answer, unless you just really want to make that answer, for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no existing method provided by tkinter.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74198450/7432) provides a function that will do it.